# What does the blue flash icon in the Outline view in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

In the Outline view for a Java source file, I have this icon next to a method:

[image: blue flash]

EDIT: When clicking the method in the Outline view, the method does not get focused in the editor.

What does it mean? There's nothing "special" about this method, here is it's signature:

```
    private void scoreAddress(ScoreResult s, ScorePosting p, ScoreOrder o, SubCategoryAddress subCategory, PrecisionAddress precision, double score, int minLength) {
    }
```

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.7.2 (Eclipse Luna SR2 4.4.2). I already had a look [at the docs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) but couldn't find that icon - so maybe it comes from the Spring extension.

Full image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the spark is an icon introduced by [AJDT 1.2](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/whatsnew12/) and means that this method is a [pointcut](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html).

The blue triangle indicates that this is a default (package visible) method [as per docs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

You can find some more info [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ajdt/)

Comment: meh - turns out it was some Eclipse problem. I removed the method and reinserted it - strange flash pointcut icon gone, normal icon here again. As your answer is probably correct for well-behaving Eclipses, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that something wasn't right but the documentation had nothing that could explain this